# Indian Phone Number RegEx

Tags: java, regex

I would like to write a RegEx to cover following phone numbers:

```
+91 33 1234 5678 (landline with two digit city code. 33 in this example)
+91 123 1234 5678 (landline with three digit city code. 123 in this example)
+91 12345 67890 (mobile no. Mobile no starts with 9 or 8 or 7)
```

Any help with explanation would be very helpful.

The code which I am using is:

```
\+91\s([\d]{2,3}\s)?[\d]{2,5}\s[\d]{3,4}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You don't need `[\d]`. Just use `\d` (no brackets)

Comment: Validating phone numbers is hard. Use an existing library, e.g. [Google's](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber).

Comment: So you are saying mobile starts with 9, 8 or 7. Then why do you give an example with 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first you need to change your regular expression first. The last number has 5 digits. So, you have to change the `4` for `5`. Then, remove the brackets. You don't need them. Then, the regular expression works in any type of language. You need to use double `\\` because `\` is an escape character.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String line = "+91 33 1234 5678 (landline with two digit city code. 33 in this example) +91 123 1234 5678 (landline with three digit city code. 123 in this example) +91 12345 67890 (mobile no. Mobile no starts with 9 or 8 or 7)";

    String pattern = "\\+91\\s(\\d{2,3}\\s)?\\d{2,5}\\s\\d{3,5}";

    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

    Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0));
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
Found value: +91 33 1234 5678
Found value: +91 123 1234 5678
Found value: +91 12345 67890
```